What is the math term for needing odd numbers of sticks in order to weave through those sticks in a circle and still have alternate weaves?
In weaving through sticks to make a circle, having even numbers of sticks will make you follow the first row of weaves and only having odd numbers of sticks will let you weave through the circle in an alternating overlaps. What math concept is that?

Do you have a visual example of what you have in mind? That might help clarify your intention.

Are your examples in a museum?  Which one?

Suppose you’re weaving a ribbon helically in and out of a bundle of $n$ sticks. Now, for a moment, consider having a necklace of $n$ beads. A basic result from elementary graph theory is that it’s possible for the necklace to contain beads of only two colors and have no two consecutive beads around the necklace be the same color if and only if $n$ is even.
Your sticks are like the beads. If we could color them not red and blue, but inside and outside, to indicate which side of a stick the ribbon should pass, and wanted the ribbon to weave in and out (so we’re alternating colors as we go around), then your number, $n$, of sticks would have to be even. That would have half the sticks always visible and the other always hidden—the two colors—and result in a basket that was an $\frac{n}{2}$-gon with the $\frac{n}{2}$ outer sticks just hanging out and never interacting with the ribbon (assuming you’re winding tightly, the sticks are spaced cylindrically, and the ribbon has negligible thickness).
Since $n$ is odd, by the next time you come back to any stick you’ll need it to change color, and changing its color means passing to the opposite side of it from the side you passed on the row before.
To summarize, the mathematical concept you’re looking for is this…

THEOREM. A graph is bipartite if and only if it contains no odd cycles.

